# Passing one connection object to multiple methods in different classes in java

Tags: java, jdbc, connection

i want to execute multiple statements in one transaction. I created a connection object and made autocommit false;

For example I got five tables that i need to update in one transaction; I made 5 classes for each class it's own update method. I used to have all those update statements in one method, but my teacher told me that it is a bad way of coding. I should have put them in different classes.

```
    public boolean updateBusinessRule(BusinessRule businessRule){
    try (Connection con = super.getConnectionConfigDb()) {
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        // Update table BusinessRule
        if (businessRule.getOperatorID() != 0) {
            String queryBr = "UPDATE BUSINESSRULE SET ERRORMESSAGE = ?, SQLCODE = ?, CUSTOMNAME = ?, OPERATOR_ID = ? WHERE BUSINESSRULE_ID = ?";
            try (PreparedStatement pstmtBr = con.prepareStatement(queryBr)) {
                pstmtBr.setString(1, businessRule.getErrorMessage());
                pstmtBr.setString(2, businessRule.getSqlQuery());
                pstmtBr.setString(3, businessRule.getName());
                pstmtBr.setInt(4, businessRule.getOperatorID());
                pstmtBr.setInt(5, businessRule.getBusinessRuleID());
                pstmtBr.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                con.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            String queryBr = "UPDATE BUSINESSRULE SET ERRORMESSAGE = ?, SQLCODE = ?, CUSTOMNAME = ? WHERE BUSINESSRULE_ID = ?";
            try (PreparedStatement pstmtBr = con.prepareStatement(queryBr)) {
                pstmtBr.setString(1, businessRule.getErrorMessage());
                pstmtBr.setString(2, businessRule.getSqlQuery());
                pstmtBr.setString(3, businessRule.getName());
                pstmtBr.setInt(4, businessRule.getBusinessRuleID());
                pstmtBr.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                con.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Update table TargetTable
        String queryTt = "UPDATE TARGETTABLE SET NAME = ? WHERE TABLE_ID = ?";
        for (int i = 0 ; i < businessRule.getTableListSize() ; i++) {
            try (PreparedStatement pstmtTt = con.prepareStatement(queryTt)) {
                pstmtTt.setString(1,businessRule.getListOfTables().get(i).getName());
                pstmtTt.setInt(2, businessRule.getListOfTables().get(i).getId());
                pstmtTt.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                con.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }


        // Update table Attribute
        String queryAt = "UPDATE ATTRIBUTE SET ATTRIBUTENAME = ?, ATTRIBUTETYPE = ?, DATALENGTH = ? WHERE ATTRIBUTE_ID = ?";
        System.out.println(businessRule.getListOfColumns().size());
        for (int i = 0 ; i < businessRule.getColumnListSize() ; i++) {
            try (PreparedStatement pstmtAt = con.prepareStatement(queryAt)) {
                pstmtAt.setString(1,businessRule.getListOfColumns().get(i).getName());
                pstmtAt.setString(2,businessRule.getListOfColumns().get(i).getDataType());
                pstmtAt.setInt(3,businessRule.getListOfColumns().get(i).getDataLength());
                pstmtAt.setInt(4,businessRule.getListOfColumns().get(i).getId());
                pstmtAt.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                con.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Update table Value
        String queryVa = "UPDATE VALUE SET VALUE = ? WHERE VALUE_ID = ?";
        for (int i = 0 ; i < businessRule.getListOfValues().size() ; i++) {
            try (PreparedStatement pstmtVa = con.prepareStatement(queryVa)) {
                pstmtVa.setInt(1,businessRule.getListOfValues().get(i).getValue());
                pstmtVa.setInt(2,businessRule.getListOfValues().get(i).getId());
                pstmtVa.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                con.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }


        // Update table Stack
        String querySt = "UPDATE BUSINESSRULESSTACK SET NAME = ? WHERE BUSINESSRULE_ID = ?";
        try (PreparedStatement pstmtSt = con.prepareStatement(querySt)) {
            pstmtSt.setString(1,businessRule.getName());
            pstmtSt.setInt(2,businessRule.getBusinessRuleID());
            pstmtSt.executeUpdate();
        } catch ( SQLException e) {
            con.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        /*
        When it reaches this point it means everything went fine so next step is commit and return true
         */

        con.commit();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

In one of the new classes called BusinessRuleDaoImpl.java i wrote the below function in it. Please note that it's calling another method in another class to executes the second statement with same connection object. I'm keep doing this till the last class. Well, i'm feeling i'm doing some bad work, don't know yet if its good practice. Can anyone advice me please? Thanks.

```
    @Override
public boolean updateBusinessRule(BusinessRule businessRule, Connection con) {
    try (Connection conBR = con) {
        if (businessRule.getOperatorID() != 0) {
            String queryBr = "UPDATE BUSINESSRULE SET ERRORMESSAGE = ?, SQLCODE = ?, CUSTOMNAME = ?, OPERATOR_ID = ? WHERE BUSINESSRULE_ID = ?";
            try (PreparedStatement pstmtBr = conBR.prepareStatement(queryBr)) {
                pstmtBr.setString(1, businessRule.getErrorMessage());
                pstmtBr.setString(2, businessRule.getSqlQuery());
                pstmtBr.setString(3, businessRule.getName());
                pstmtBr.setInt(4, businessRule.getOperatorID());
                pstmtBr.setInt(5, businessRule.getBusinessRuleID());
                pstmtBr.executeUpdate();
                return tableDao.updateTable(businessRule,conBR);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                con.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            String queryBr = "UPDATE BUSINESSRULE SET ERRORMESSAGE = ?, SQLCODE = ?, CUSTOMNAME = ? WHERE BUSINESSRULE_ID = ?";
            try (PreparedStatement pstmtBr = con.prepareStatement(queryBr)) {
                pstmtBr.setString(1, businessRule.getErrorMessage());
                pstmtBr.setString(2, businessRule.getSqlQuery());
                pstmtBr.setString(3, businessRule.getName());
                pstmtBr.setInt(4, businessRule.getBusinessRuleID());
                pstmtBr.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                con.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is to give each table/entity its own DAO, Service, and Controllers. The Business Rules table would have its object in Java, a BusinessRules Dao, a BusinessRulesService, and BusinessRulesController. The same would be true of Value, Attributable, etc. The Services can talk to each other to update all 5 tables at in one method. The Dao's should only talk to its Service and DTO.

Comment: Thank you Chase, i appreciate your comment.